# Unable to create user for a restored database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I started a few developments in a developed ASP.NET web site. I restored the Db successfully to the SQL Server 2012, and once I created a new login for a user **wilsondbuser**. And I worked with it very well.

After 2 days, when I visit to the SQL Server again, there was no that created user in the Security tab of relevant Db. But the user was in the SQl Server Security tab. And also no any table displayed.

So, I deleted that user, only exist in the Security tab of relevant Db. Then I tried to create the same user in SQL Server. Then it displayed following error.

[image]

Please help me to again work with that restored database.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps solved the problem:

1. Copy database files to another location
2. Delete main files
3. Restart SQL Service.
4. In management studio the database will be shown with "Recovery Pending" in front of its name, delete it.
5. Attach your database with copied files of the first step.
6. Create the user you want.